# Assume that $F_n$ denote Fibonacci number for integer $n$. How can we prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}F_{2n}x^n=\frac{x}{1-3x+x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, power-series, fibonacci-numbers

Assume that $F_n$ denote Fibonacci number for integer $n$. It is proved that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}F_nx^n=\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}.$ How can we prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}F_{2n}x^n=\frac{x}{1-3x+x^2}$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating function of a Fibonacci series but with certain variation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3708515/generating-function-of-a-fibonacci-series-but-with-certain-variation)

Comment: Or this? [Generating Function of Even Fibonacci](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174341/generating-function-of-even-fibonacci)

Comment: Thanks.  I try to find an elementary  solution.  The similar question is: How can we prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}F_{2n+1}x^n=\frac{1-x}{1-3x+x^2}$. This formula can be a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$ f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}F_nx^n=\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}. $$
Then
$$ f(x)+f(-x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}F_n(x^n+(-1)^nx^n)=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}F_{2n}x^n $$
and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}F_{2n}x^{2n}\\
&=&\frac12\bigg(\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}+\frac{-x}{1+x-x^2}\bigg)\\
&=&\frac12\frac{x(1+x-x^2)-x(1-x-x^2))}{(1-x^2)^2-x^2}\\
&=&\frac{x^2}{1-3x^2+x^4}.
\end{eqnarray}
So
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}F_{2n}x^n
=\frac{x}{1-3x+x^2}. $$